# Htaccess Re-write rules problems with chrome displaying web pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Website displays correctly on IE. Chrome will not dislpay correctly or follow links. Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated. If I remove the htaccess file, google displays correctly and links work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
#services
RewriteRule ^index.html$                   index.php                          [L]
RewriteRule ^showthread_([^/]*).html$      index.php?method=showthread&id=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^postcomment.html$             index.php                          [L]
RewriteRule ^maturecontent.html$           index.php?method=maturecontent     [L]
RewriteRule ^randomthread.html$            index.php?method=randomthread      [L]
RewriteRule ^readnotapproved.html$         index.php?method=readnotapproved   [L]
RewriteRule ^contacts.html$                index.php?method=contacts          [L]
RewriteRule ^about.html$                   index.php?method=aboutus           [L]
```

Comment: `.htaccess` could not have less to do with your browser- have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Currently my web page parses as http://foo.com/fooo/index.html on IE on chrome it parses as http://foo.com/fooo/foo.com/fooo/index.html which displays everything incorrectly and leaves improper links. the config script is as follows defines the base url. $this->headers['baseurl'] = "";  <-left this way 'blank' chrome parses the website correctly, but IE fails to parse correctly. Changing the base url to foo.com/foo/ causes the reverse to occur IE functions properly and chrome fails. The exact same is true with removing the Htaccess file. Removing it Chrome functions properly.

Comment: Figured it out after looking at my php code. Thanks archio you were right htaccess was just a symptom of another problem which had nothing do with my browser. My base url needed to be formatted in a strict way, "http://www.foo.com/fooo/ ".

Comment: Great! I'll post as an answer so people can see the result next time.

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess` files are on the server-side: they handle requests by the **client**, and return resources (like HTML or image files) to the browser.

The **browser**, in turn, interprets this HTML code and/or resources and displays a webpage with it's rendering engine.

You said that there are differences between browsers in displaying your page. This is entirely possible, but it is impossible that the cause is an .htaccess file, because *all browsers, no matter what type, are always given the same code when requesting from a server*.

If there is a difference in appearance on the site between browsers, and you believe the cause to be an .htaccess file, it probably means there is an issue with your browser's **cache** of the page. Browsers, as they should, cache (or save locally) some data to save time as to not have to request the same data again and again every time a page is accessed. Sometimes, there are inconsistencies with this- so you can fix this problem by clearing your browser's cache.

If this is not the issue, keep checking your layout and/or URL scheme, but I assure you it has nothing to do with .htaccess.